# Dirac delta function forcing in 1st order ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dirac-delta

We have $$\frac{dT}{dt}=-a(T-T_{\infty})-\delta (t-1)$$ where $T_{\infty}$ is a constant and $\delta$ is the Dirac delta.

> Determine the jump (discontinuity) condition for $T$ at $t=1$ and
>   hence find $T(t)$ for $t>1$.

I'm just a little puzzled as this is first order. I have only ever done second order before. Is $T$ continuous at $t=1$ here? What is the jump condition? I think I just need a run down of what is actually going on here, for me this is very much a method at the moment, I see these questions I have a procedure to solve them rather than actually comprehending everything that's going on. My method doesn't work here do I can't do it.

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

As usual, employ the exponential integrating factor to get
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}(e^{at}(T(t)-T_∞))&=e^{at}\,δ(t−1)=e^{a·1}\,δ(t−1)
\\[1em]
e^{at}(T(t)-T_∞)-(T(0)-T_∞)
&=-e^{a}\,\int_0^tδ(s−1)\,ds
\\
&=-e^a·H(t-1)
\end{align}
where $H$ is the Heaviside jump function.

Answer (score 1):

Let $u=L\{\frac{dT}{dt}\}$, where $L$ is Laplace Transform. Then after taking Laplace Transform for both sides of the equation, one has
$$ L\{\frac{dT}{dt}\}=-aL\{(T-T_{\infty})\}-L\{\delta (t-1)\}$$
or
$$ su(s)-T(0)=-a(u(s)-\frac{T_\infty}{s})-e^{-s}. $$
Thus
$$ u(s)=\frac{e^{-s}}{s+a}+\frac{aT_\infty}{s(s+a)}+\frac{T(0)}{s+a}.$$
So
$$ T(t)=L^{-1}(u(s))=e^{-a t}(-e^a \theta (t-1)+T_\infty (e^{a t}-1)+T(0))$$
where $\theta$ is Heaviside Theta. So one has, for $t<1$,
$$ T(t)=e^{-a t} (T_\infty \left(e^{a t}-1\right)+T(0))$$
and for $t\ge 1$,
$$ T(t)=e^{-a t}(-e^a+T_\infty (e^{a t}-1)+T(0)).$$